# Python: where do i find information on {!r}?

Tags: python

i saw this: `{!r}` in some code today and i've been searching all over hell's half acre to find information on it.  the attendant comment was that it called the internal `__repr__`, but what threw me was that the `{!r}` was *inside* the `__repr__` itself:

```py
def __repr__(self):
  return "{!r}".format(self.__dict__)
```

::confused noises::

can someone point me to where i can learn more about this?

Comment: The `__repr__` for THAT CLASS is going to return the `__repr__` for its dictionary.  It's not recursive in any way.  It's just passing the authority along to the next guy.

Comment: You are using python2 right?

Comment: nope.  Python 3.

Comment: @TimRoberts  ok, yup, but that's not the question.  :P  where do i read about that?

Comment: That was exactly the question. `{!r}` calls `__repr__`, so that code is exactly the same as `return repr(self.__dict__)` which is the same as `return self.__dict__.__repr__()`.

Comment: Since you are looking for the documentation: [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) leads you to [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings).